# Query - Calculate the difference between 2 DB tables with the same columns

Tags: sql

How do you calculate the difference between 2 DB tables with the same columns using query? They both have Columns as 'app', 'installs', 'usage'. Thanks in advance.

My notworking query

```
WITH apps AS (
SELECT app, installs_curr, usage_curr FROM (
    SELECT app, installs AS installs_curr, usage AS usage_curr
    FROM e5a.apps_2020_07
    )
SELECT app, installs_prev, usage_prev FROM (
   SELECT app, installs AS installs_prev, usage AS usage_prev
    FROM e5a.apps_2020_06
    )
)
SELECT app, installs_curr – installs_prev AS installs_delta, usage_curr – usage_prev AS usage_delta FROM apps
ORDER BY usage_delta DESC
```

```
**TABLE e5a.apps_2020_07**

app   installs usage 
snap  20       10

**TABLE e5a.apps_2020_06**

app   installs usage 
snap  12       8
  
**Result through calculation**

app   installs usage 
snap  8       2
```

Comment: (1) I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  (2) What do YOU mean by "difference"?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Thanks. An example is monthly installation (installs) values change, gain or loss. 10 (installs_curr) - 4 (installs_prev) = 6 (installs_delta).

Comment: . . Sample data and explanation belong *in the question*, not in a comment.  You can edit the question.

Comment: ok, sample data are added.

Comment: You'll want to JOIN the two tables ON "app"

Comment: In your two tables how do you identify that value of 1st row is to be subtracted from 1st row or 2nd row... of second table, theer should be some column to join the two tables or if you can order the two tables by some colum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you want to treat values in one table but not the other.  A good place to start is with `join`:

```
SELECT a7.app,
       (a7.installs - a6.installs) AS installs_diff,
       (a7.usage - a6.usage) AS usage_diff
FROM e5a.apps_2020_07 a7 JOIN
     e5a.apps_2020_08 a6
     ON a7.apps = a6.apps;
```

This include only apps that are in both tables.

You should fix your data model so you have only one table with the month as a column in the table.

Comment: Mr. Linoff, I take my hat off. 1M reputation points is no small deal. Of course it's just a number... but it's a big one. That's like 40x what it as taken me 2 years to accomplish. Congratulations!

Comment: [Congratulations on the 1M](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400506/1983854)!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that App is primary key, then you can simply subtract:

```
SELECT a.app, a.installs - b.installs installs_curr, a.usage - b.usage  AS usage_curr
    FROM e5a.apps_2020_07 a inner join e5a.apps_2020_06 b on (a.app = b.app)
```